# Algorithmic game theory and decentralized exchange of information

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, computation, algorithms

An intresting topic that I want to understad has to do with the decentralized exchange of information among a network of agents, however there is not a specific theory to make such a mathematical model and computer sience seems to have made many steps helping to make model such problems. I have the following question which arises after I have read some papers and in the last one they refer for [to communication networks](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00367692/document) while the previous papers where having a discussion in communication mechanisms or protocols

What is the difference between a communication mechanism a protocol of exchanging information and communication network of agents who act strategically based on the extraneous information that they observer befoe starting to communicate and the endogenous informations that they acquire throuth the communication phase and before they make they final decisions to play in the game?